# Is it equivalent to translate inside the component or the component itself?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, translation

I try this code (JSFiddle)

```
const Piece = () => {
return (
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(XXX,XXX)">
    <circle cx="-50" cy="-50" r="10" fill="black" />
  </g>
  </svg>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));

root.render(
  <svg width="700" height="700" fill="#FFDDDD">
    <g transform="translate(YYY,YYY)">
      <Piece />
    </g>
  </svg>
);
```

where the XXX and YYY equals to 0 or 100, and I can see that:

- if the translation takes place inside the component Piece (XXX=100, YYY=0), it works in the sense that the circle appears on the screen even if it is designed outside the screen initially (-50, -50);
- if the translation takes place inside the main component (XXX=0, YYY=100), the circle doesn't appear.

I thought it was the same to translate inside or outside, but it is not. The thing is that I want to gather many different parts and it's not a good thing to transmit values of translation to all these parts...

Of course, I have tested the code on a true React (18) with d3 (7) structure with different files Piece, App, etc. and the result is the same.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that you don't need React or d3js for figuring this one out in the slightest: SVG is part of the HTML5 spec, so you can just compare two SVG elements directly, instead of chopping them up. Easier for folks to read  that way, too. The real question is why your `Piece` is a separate `<svg>` element though. Why isn't that just a `<g>`? (also, note that your svg is  missing the `viewBox` attribute)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Of course, this is just an extract of what is problematic for me. The whole real code I work on has no circle at all to render ;)... Your second question is true and profound to me because what I want to do is separate React logic from d3's, and avoiding getting a 400 lines file with all the d3 staff in a useEffect, as I've seen many times on blogs. So spliting the code in components seems to me be the appropriate way. Bu I am open to any comments on this, and references too! Thanks.

Comment: Then you'll want to (re)read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and the (short) article on how to create a [mcve]: even if you intend to split things in your own code, if the _problem_ can be shown off without it, then doing so makes for a far better question, both for folks trying to answer it, _and_ future visitors who might not be using react or d3 but have the exact same problem with a different stack that can also be reduced to "but really, it's just a plain SVG question" =)

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't understand where the problem is. To me, this question is a whole: the React component+the d3 aspect. I read again the minimal reproductible example and can't see what I did wrong. Let me know in order to be able to improve my questions, if you think it's worth it. Thank you :-).

Comment: Mostly the part where your question isn't _about_ react or d3, it's _just_ about the composition of the SVG itself, and the fact that you can slice it up using React, or that d3 uses SVG under the hood, is simply unrelated to the problem here. Part of the "MCVE" work would have been to uncollapse the SVG in your react to a single return, which would _still_ reproduce the problem, so having the code split up wasn't a contributing factor, and so you can further simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your SVG properly, then it doesn't matter which `<g>` you use for that translation. In fact, you don't need a `<g>` at all if you're transforming a single element because the "transform" attribute can be used on *any* SVG element unless you want to transform groups (hence the "g") of elements.

So: one `<svg>` root, with a `viewBox` attribute so the browser knows what it's actually rendering, and no nesting `<svg>` inside `<svg>` unless you absolutely have to (and if you have to ask when you might have to, then you don't). And you can't set a "fill" on the SVG root element, but you can use CSS for a background color, or you can create a `<rect fill="..." ... />` with the appropriate dimensions.

```css
svg { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g transform="translate(100,100)">
    <circle cx="-50" cy="-50" r="10" fill="black" />
  </g>
</svg>

<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="-50" cy="-50" r="10" fill="black" transform="translate(100,100)" />
</svg>
```

So if you turn that into something composable, your `Piece` is just a circle (no need for a `<g>` unless you want to place more than one, and then the `<g>` goes around your collection of `Piece`s):

```
const Piece = ({ tx=0, ty=0 }) => (
  <circle cx="-50" cy="-50" r="10" fill="black" transform="translate({tx},{ty})"/>
);

// But you need viewBox, otherwise your SVG cannot be rendered correctly.
const SVG = ({ tx=0, ty=0 }) => (
  <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <Piece tx={tx} ty={ty}/>
  </svg>
);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));
root.render(<SVG tx={100} ty={100}/>);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand reading it that I lacked something on the difference between viewport and width/height of svg! I'm having a look at that and come back after...

Comment: OK, it works. The problem was the svg in the Piece component. I removed it and it works (i.e. translation is effective when set inside container component).

Comment: `width` and `height` are attributes "for the thing that's putting the SVG in a document", so that it knows how much space it'll take up even before it renders it. The `viewBox` attribute is [for the SVG itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox), indicating which part of the _infinitely large area_ should be visible. Because vector graphics have no "bounds", there is no pixel array that it can't draw outside of, so you need to say what counts as "visible" =)

Comment: Oh yes! I have added the viewBox as you explained, but it didn't solve the problem of translation. What solved it is to delete the extra svg tag inside the component. And even without the viewBox, it works (if the svg is removed). That's what I wanted to say in the previous message.

Comment: Ah. Yeah: no nesting `<svg>` elements, it just doesn't make any sense to, that content would just be "more content in the same SVG document" =)